# linux command to combine multiple columns in a tab-delim file?

Tags: linux, command-line, command

everyone!

How can I convert this

```
a     2     3     4 
b     3     1     6
c     3     5     2 
d     6     3     5
```

to below?

```
a-2:3     4
b-3:1     6
c-3:5     2
d-6:3     5
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [awk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/), in your case :

```
awk -F \\t '{print $1"-"$2$3":"$4}' < input.txt
```

if the input is in the `input.txt` file or you can even pipe to [awk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/)

Comment: what exactly is '\\t' for?

Comment: the -F parameter specify the delimiter `\\t` is an escaped version of `\t`for parameter parsing, which mean that `\\` is converted to `\`when passed to awk